# Change page-break interval depending on the group header

Tags: javascript, birt

My report is grouped by customers and products.
The parent table contains the customer information, and the each child table(embedded in the detail row of the parent) shows details of individual products.

I am stuck at one requirement:
"Display the customer information only on the first page." 
It sounds simple. Just display it in the group header and turn off "Repeat Header" option. But I am at a loss how to change different page break interval for the page with the group header, and the rest of pages without it.

The report should be output to PDF, A4, fixed layout(because it uses page-variable)

Each product has individual page-break setting(as they display different kind of information, some can show 10 rows in a page, some only 5).
To make the first page of the customer to display the group header and the detail rows nicely, I have to reduce the number of rows from the page break setting, but if I do that, it will reduce the number of rows the rest of pages can display.

If possible, I want to customize the page-break setting so it changes whether the page has the group header or not.

The difficulties I found include:
1) how to know which product will be displayed for a customer
2) how to write a script for custom page break. For example, if a page has a group header, the page only displays 5 detail rows to open the space of the header. But the next page will display 10 detail rows.

1) How to know what will be the customer's first product? There are about 10 products the customer may or may not have.

Comment: You said "Each product has individual page-break setting". Why do you have to specify a page-break interval at all? It should hardly pe necessary to specify any number except 1 or 9999 (maximum value), as the PDF emitter will insert page breaks as necessary anyway.

Comment: Because it is one of the customer's requirements. They will modify the report afterward not using BIRT(such as adding some analysis data, I think) so I have to maintain a certain margin underneath the tables and the required margin varies for each product, sometimes at the half, sometimes 3/4 of the page.

Comment: Can't you just add double labels in the table headers and show/hide them based on the pageNumber > 1?

Comment: Don't know exactly of this helps you, but to reserve space at the end for the customer to modify the report, you could just insert an empty 1x1 grid with fixed height (or even set the height dynamically in the grid's onCreate script). That way you can still use the automatic page breaking capabilities of BIRT.